# Grouping on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with following columns:

```
Id(int), StoreId(int), StoreCode(nvarchar), StartDate(date), EndDate(date)
```

It has some records with same StoreId, StartDate, EndDate, but different StoreCodes. I wold like to select these store codes (for which rest of the data is duplicated in two or more records).
How can I group this properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  StoreId, StoreDate, EndDate, COUNT(DISTINCT StoreCode) AS Count
FROM MyTableName
GROUP BY StoreId, StoreDate, EndDate
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT StoreCode) > 1
```

Will return (StoreId, StoreDate, EndDate) combination and number of `DISTINCT StoreCode`s associated with that combination when there are at least 2 occurrences.